# Navigation bar not working properly in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im currently working in ASP.NET and have some trouble resolving this issue.
I have this code in HTML like this

```
 <li><a href="#">Rooms</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Regular</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Deluxe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">King's</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
```

Then ofcourse I want it to be like a pop up when I hover it. So i added this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function mainmenu() {
            $(" #nav ul ").css({ display: "none" });
            $("#nav li").hover(function () {
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility:"visibile",display:"none"}).show(200);
            }
            , function () {
                $(this).find ('ul:first').css ({visibility:"hidden"});
            })
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            mainmenu();
        });
        </script>
```

All is working well on the first time I hover on the "Room" link, but when i hover someplace else then hover it back to "Room" it didn't pop-up. Help?

Comment: jQuery version 1.3.2?!  Are you running this code in IE 6?

Comment: No sir, I'm running this at Chrome.

Comment: My point was that jQuery 1.3.2 is a dinosaur that is over 5 years old.

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't get the sarcasm lol. But nevertheless it's still bugging me why 1.3.2 and 2.1.1 still share the same results. The reason why i'm using 1.3.2 because it is the version my classmate gave to me and im new in jquery :P

Comment: I didn't say a newer version of jQuery would fix anything, but with something that old, you're asking for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery 1.3.2 is over 5 years old, please update to the latest version, it seems to fix your problem (it's safe and usually the best to load jQuery straight from Google, so you don't have to store it locally):

**Live:** http://jsfiddle.net/6ynafsxr/

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mainmenu() {
        $(" #nav ul ").css({ display: "none" });
        $("#nav li").hover(function () {
            $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility:"visibile",display:"none"}).show(200);
        }
        , function () {
            $(this).find ('ul:first').css ({visibility:"hidden"});
        })
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        mainmenu();
    });
</script>
```

Also, why don't you use CSS for that? Can't you just simply use "display: block" on :hover state? With animations it will look something like:

### Pure CSS version

```
#nav ul {
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

**Live:** http://jsfiddle.net/6ynafsxr/1/

[edit]

### Full version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mainmenu() {

    $("#nav ul").css({ display: "none" }); // you should use CSS for that
    $("#nav li").hover(function () {
        $("ul", this).css({visibility:"visible", display: "none"}).show(200);
        $("ul", this).addClass("test");
    }, function() {
        $("ul", this).css({visibility:"hidden"});
        $("ul", this).removeClass("test");
    })
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    mainmenu();
});
</script>
</head>

<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Rooms</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Regular</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Deluxe</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">King's</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically you were using selectors wrongly, I still strongly suggest to use CSS instead of jQuery for this menu as it looks like an overkill to use JS here.

Comment: Hi sir! Thank you for your effort. I have a few things that I notice whilst I follow your advice and code. I check out on the live version of the JS. and it turns out working fine and so as the CSS version. But when I apply the latest version of JS which is 2.1.1, the problem still comeback that the whenever I hover on it the second time, it doesn't show up.
P.S. I didnt load the jquery on google because it isn't efficient for me because sometimes I work at school and we don't have Wifi

Comment: I see, please check the edit, it should get you going :)

Answer (score 1):

something like this? the problem is that on `mouseenter` you're setting `display none` and not changing the display back to normal when mouse leaves. remember `visibility != display`

## [Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/8b2b113d2eff87c16bf0b9308bdacabd)

```
<div id='nav'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Rooms</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Regular</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Deluxe</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">King's</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
    <li><a href="#">Rooms</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Regular</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Deluxe</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">King's</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
function mainmenu() {
    $("#nav li ul").css({ display: "none" });
    $("#nav").on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'li', function() {
        $(this).children('ul').fadeToggle("fast");
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    mainmenu();
});
```